# How do you use Thrift's TMemoryBuffer in Golang?

Tags: go, thrift

In Go, I have a byte array `data []byte` which I am trying to read into an object generated by Thrift.  In C# the working code is as follows:

```
var request = new Request();

using (var transport = new TMemoryBuffer(data))
using (var protocol = new TBinaryProtocol(transport))
{
   request.Read(protocol);
}
```

However in Go, it does not work:

```
request := app.NewRequest()

transport := thrift.TMemoryBuffer{
    Buffer: bytes.NewBuffer(data),
}
protocol := thrift.NewTBinaryProtocolTransport(transport) // error here
request.Read(protocol)
```

The error it gives is:

```
cannot use memoryBuffer (type thrift.TMemoryBuffer) as type thrift.TTransport in argument to thrift.NewTBinaryProtocolTransport:
thrift.TMemoryBuffer does not implement thrift.TTransport (Close method has pointer receiver)
```

I am unsure of how to fix this, as `TMemoryBuffer` does not seem to implement `TTransport` and I can't find documentation of how `TMemoryBuffer` should be used instead.

Comment: Have you tried using [`NewTMemoryBuffer`](https://godoc.org/github.com/nporsche/golang-thrift#NewTMemoryBuffer) instead of creating a type explicitly?

Comment: @abhink That is working, thank you!  However I cannot understand why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The important part of that error is `Close method has pointer receiver`.

A function can be defined on a type, or a pointer to that type (i.e a pointer receiver), the `TTransport` interface defines a function Close with a pointer receiver.

Read the [tour of go](https://tour.golang.org/methods/4) for a refresher on pointer receivers.

Changing your code to the following, should work:

```
transport := &thrift.TMemoryBuffer{
    Buffer: bytes.NewBuffer(data),
}
```

One way to think about the problem would be that `thrift.TMemoryBuffer` does not have `Close` function defined on it, but that `*thrift.TMemoryBuffer` does. And the function `NewTBinaryProtocolTransport` requires a type with a `Close` function defined as specified by the interface.

Comment: Gosh I can't believe I was tearing my hair out over a missing ampersand!  Thank you for the in depth answer and explanation.  It all makes sense now.